# Is there a way to signin Xero api using oauth2 in c# desktop application?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, xero-api, pkce

There are several .Net sample codes that using oauth2 to signin Xero, but all of them is working with browser (most of the sample code for C# is for ASP.NET MVC).

I am going to develop a desktop application using Xero Api but Xero official tutorial said that mobile or desktop application should use PKCE flow instead of using ClientID/Secret scheme.

And in this PKCE flow, user should interact with browser to get Authorization code.

I want to know if there is any way to signin without user interaction.

Comment: There's a [GitHub](https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard) repo for that.

Comment: Thank @Corey. I also checked the code, but the codes are all working with a browser. I am looking for a solution without user interaction.

Comment: Uh... no? The API in there is for .NET programs. It doesn't require or interact with a browser or ASP.NET.

Comment: @Corey would you share me the actual project name you have ran? or screenshot how it runs?

Comment: If you look at the "machine to machine" tutorial video on the Xero youtube channel, it may help you. Use XOAuth to generate your first pair of tokens, and then have your appliction refresh them as required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xero api signin was just migrated to use OAuth2.0 and it should interact with browser at least once.
Once you get refresh_token using offline_access scope, you will use this token to get access token.
Unfortunately they don't support custom url scheme.
Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks spica for your answer. Have you tested with C# application?

Comment: Yes, I also had encountered same issue, and tried several days to solve this, but finally I found it is impossible. You can use Partner app of Xero.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and there were no examples of how to do this.

As mentioned you need to create a refresh token (which does mean you have to open a browser at some point), but after that you can keep refreshing the token to get new access tokens.  A refresh token can be used only once so you must store the new refresh token after each use. You must make sure to only allow one program/thread to refreshes the token at a time.  Refresh tokens will expire after 60 days if they're not refreshed.

I created a [worked example on github](https://github.com/JWealthall/XeroOAuth2ApiPkceHowTo) to show how to do this.

Since I produced this Xero have sent me a link to a new [desktop based program](https://github.com/XeroAPI/net-desktop-pkce-example) which replaces their [XOAuth console program](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xoauth) for generating the refresh token.

Now that .Net 5 is available you could look at embedding Edge into the application for when you have to log into Xero